# How to replace 'px' by '%' in .scroll jQuery Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm using Wordpress and what to replace 'px' by '%' in .scroll jQuery Function. Here is the code with 'px' option working (at http://robo.im) -

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 200) { 
            $('.home #masthead').css("opacity", 0.98);
        }
        else{
            $('.home #masthead').css("opacity", 0);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: for 5% try `if ($(window).scrollTop() > window.height * .05) {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just calculate the percentage by using the scrolled distance and the total height

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var height  = Math.max.apply(null, [$('body').prop('scrollHeight'),$('html').prop('scrollHeight')]),
            percent = $(window).scrollTop() / (height - $(window).height()) * 100;
        if (percent > 20) { 
            $('.home #masthead').css("opacity", 0.98);
        }
        else{
            $('.home #masthead').css("opacity", 0);
        }
    });
});
```